# How to install GGRAPH package to the latest R (v.3.3.2)

Tags: r, package, ggraph

I am very new to R and I need ggraph library and it can't be installed from rstudio console. Here is a message:

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘ggraph’ is not available (for
>   R version 3.3.2)

Are there other ways of installation? Looks like this library lives and flourishes:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/introduction-to-ggraph-layouts/

Comment: I tried this:
install_github("thomasp85/ggraph")
but ended up with an error message `Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: mebbe `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/ggraph", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: NOTE ^^ implies you've installed `devtools` already which you need to care abt `udunits2` libraries as noted in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires`udunits2` library.

I use conda R, so I installed it using `conda install -c ioos udunits2=2.2.20`. You need to use a package manager to get it installed.

Then install the `udunits2` R package

```
install.packages('udunits2', type = "source",
                     configure.args=c('--with-udunits2-lib=/Users/Karthik/anaconda/lib'))
```

Replace `/Users/Karthik/anaconda/lib` with the path to your R libraries. You can find it using `.libPaths()`

Finally install the development version of [R packages](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph)

```
devtools::install_github("thomasp85/ggraph", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: I did like that having in mind your reply:
1) `install.packages("udunits2")`
2) `library(udunits2)`
3) exactly your final piece
`if(!require(devtools)) {
    install.packages('devtools')
}
devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')
devtools::install_github('thomasp85/ggforce')
devtools::install_github('thomasp85/ggraph')`
And it worked :). Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/ggraph", dependencies=TRUE)` after you've taken care of the C library dependency?